# No right answer to my question

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, specific-question

I have posted this question and all i got are workarounds, because its apparently not possible to do it. What are you doing when you are not satisfied by the answers you got?

[Can I disable a CSS :hover effect via JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2754546/prevent-hover-set-by-the-css)

What would you do? Give the right answer to the compromise you like best?

Comment: lol at @gnoupi's edit

Comment: How many programmers does it take ... ? :)

Comment: @balpha - no more Meta on weekend :]

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42049/my-bounty-is-about-to-expire-and-i-didnt-get-a-good-answer-just-my-own-workarou

Comment: @Josh: thx for this, i think if did not find it because the title is not very explicit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pick the answer that says it can't be done and contains the workaround that works best for you.

Comment: its what I was thinking to. Could i extend my bounty somehow? (Give more points away or something...)

Comment: @meo: Nope. And if you don't pick an answer then the bounty is lost.

Comment: Actually Paul D. Waite's answer will be auto-accepted if you don't pick one.

Answer (score 6):

You don't **have** to accept any answer at all. If the answers offered genuinely don't solve the problem, don't feel compelled to "pick" one at all. You might still up-vote those that taught you something, however, to show willing.

Comment: This is a good answer, but it does mean that I can't achieve 100% "accepted" score for my questions. I want to write good questions that people want to answer, but sometimes an answer just doesn't come up.  I suppose I could write my own answer and accept that?

Comment: @Neil: If you figure it out yourself and that solution isn't posted yet, posting it yourself is encouraged. However, not every question has a satisfactory answer and you don't need to have 100% accept rate (i personally consider >80% high).

Comment: @Neil: Too many people place too much emphasis on accept rate.  It's tempting to do so.

Comment: Well I place at least *some* emphasis on it, because I'd like those people who are considering taking the time to answer my questions to know that I care about receiving those answers and appreciate their effort.

Answer (score 2):

A quote:

> Insanity: doing the same thing over
>   and over again and expecting different
>   results.  Albert Einstein

I'm sure you're not crazy, but have you considered the possibility that the thing you want just isn't out there? So, don't accept any answer, and go sit for a while and think through your next best plan.

Comment: i like this answer :P sadly i have already accepted one but still +1 for this

Answer (score 0):

Eventually you'll solve your problem yourself.  In which case, write that answer up for other people to benefit from and mark it as the accepted answer.