# What if I offer a bounty and don't get any good answers?

Tags: support, bounties, accepted-answer

I have started a bounty:
[Select videos using UIImagePickerController in 2G/3G](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2758466/select-videos-using-uiimagepickercontroller-in-2g-3g)

It expires in 3 days. I don't have an appropriate answer to accept, and the only answer which it has gotten has no votes.

So am I going to simply lose 100 reputation without getting a satisfactory answer?

Or should I accept the lone inappropriate answer so that I will not lose my right to accept answers to any questions which I might ask in the future, which is what the bounty rules claim?

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42049/my-bounty-is-about-to-expire-and-i-didnt-get-a-good-answer-just-my-own-workarou

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> So am I gonna loose the 100 reputation
>   just simply without having my answer?

Yes

> should I accept the lone
>   un-appropriate answer so that I will
>   not loose my right to accept answers
>   to any questions which I might ask in
>   future, which is what the rules of
>   bounty claims?

No, It does not effect your other questions. So you can choose the most appropriate one or accept your own answer or don't just accept it. Its your choice.

For more info, see [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work) faq question

Comment: Thanks Mark, that makes things clear!

Comment: I'm very sad to find out the reputation is just lost. Nobody gains from it. It's wasted.