# Offer bounty refund on "good" question with no answers

Tags: feature-request, bounties

Question: [Looking for tips to build “TestMaker” (Questions and Responses) application with Evaluation Engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8001070/looking-for-tips-to-build-testmaker-questions-and-responses-application-with)

There is a feature that gives the bounty amount to any answer with 2 votes.
(If the person who issues the bounty does not choose an answer.)
Which is a good feature.

My suggestion would be to have a corresponding bounty-refunder.

If the question itself gets 2 or more votes, but no answer is chosen by the person issuing the bounty or the auto-bounty-picker does not kick in....then the person who issued the bounty should get all or some credit back.

My questions seemed to be a decent one (4 votes).  But no answer was up-voted.  (Or detailed enough IMHO to award the bounty.)

Maybe I'm not seeing something, if so, let me know.

I know this has been discussed before:

- [Bounty Points Refund [closed]](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73468/bounty-points-refund)
- [What if I offer a bounty and don't get any good answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49394/what-if-i-offer-a-bounty-and-dont-get-any-good-answers)

I'm not complaining about not getting my points back.  (I understand the current policy and accept it.)

**If no answers meet these criteria, the bounty ends without it being awarded to any answer, and is not refunded to the bounty starter.**

I'm suggesting a new consideration when the "Question got UP-Voted", but no answers were bounty-awarding-worth answers.
Or maybe a partial refund to prevent bounty mis-use.

But sometimes someone asks a decent question, and there wasn't any bounty-awarding-worth answers.

Comment: Upvotes already are a partial refund of the bounty.

Comment: Thanks (Bill the Lizard), I didn't know that one.

Comment: @BilltheLizard I regularly offer bounties on other questions if I'm not able to answer. So I don't get any upvotes.

Comment: @Maarten This was asked back in 2011, before we could put bounties on other people's posts.

Comment: @BilltheLizard OK, but I have put quite a bit of rep. at stake to try to have answers to interesting (cryptography related) questions on SO in case I could not answer. Currently I'm constantly seeing those points to up into smoke, which frustrates the heck out of me and stops me from offering bounties in the first place. So maybe that policy has changed, but the bounty system hasn't otherwise been amended.

Answer (score 6):

Lets assume the following.

1. I put a bounty on a question
2. You give an answer deserving of the bounty by content but not by vote.
3. The question meets some criteria were I get some of the bounty back.

Under today's rules there's no reason why I wouldn't award you the bounty. (Since #3 never happens)

With your rules you're giving me an incentive to not award you the bounty. I'm sure you agree that's a bad thing.

Comment: Ok.I can see it both ways.  //You give an answer deserving of the bounty by content but not by vote.//  I agree, some might be inclined not to award the bounty......The counter thought would be .. "if an answer was good, 2 people out there, somewhere, would vote it up".  But thanks for supplying the alternative viewpoint.  While it probably doesn't matter what I think in the grand scope of things, I'm good with the existing policy.

Comment: Voted down. Although there is no pressure to award the bounty wrt reputation, I'm not sure if people would play the system the way you describe. And there would certainly be peer pressure to award it. And if an answer cannot even gain two upvotes, then is it really that good?