# Partial bounty refund for good question with no answers

Tags: feature-request, answers, bounties

I understand that there has been a post in the past:

[Offer bounty refund on "good" question with no answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/112823/offer-bounty-refund-on-good-question-with-no-answers)

That has addressed this exactly but as a feature request, perhaps this is a new topic. I read the complete bounty award system, and understand that bounty is a price to pay in reputation to get attention to complicated questions and accept it with a pinch of salt. However, there maybe times when featured questions don't get any answers. I completely understand that the author chose no provided answers but in that case, people did answer his question. I wanted to ask why and how a bounty system could be exploited if you got lot of up-votes (let's say 5) and no answers and your bounty expired, this is just a waste of the reputation perhaps. Could there be a partial refund of the bounty, with an emphasis on the amount offered as well as the amount of upvotes it got because it got featured. I'd appreciate some thoughts on this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Could there be a partial refund of the bounty, with an emphasis on the amount offered as well as the amount of upvotes it got because it got featured.

If you offer a bounty on your own question (which happens [in no less than 84% of the bounties on Stack Overflow](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/904169/bounties-on-own-questions-vs-others-questions)) the reputation gained from upvotes *already* form a partial refund of the bounty, even in the case when you *do* get a satisfying answer.

Otherwise, a bounty can be thought of an advertisement. Companies that sell advertising space rarely give refunds if your campaign wasn't successful, so I doubt anything like this is going to happen on Stack Exchange.

Answer (score -2):

I for one think such a feature would be fair: even advertisement companies often bill you on "pay per click" basis, so if your ad campaign is not successful, you end up paying less. However, no ad company will accept to vouch that the customers you get will bring you any profits.

The problem I see is that such a refund system might create more problems that it solves. For instance, I sometimes answer bountied questions in a way that challenges the questions's premises i.e.

> You have an X/Y problem here: instead of trying to do X, which is the core of the question but very hard to do properly, you should think about alternatives to achieve Y. It might be that you actually don't even need Y that much, so the whole thing is not worth the effort.

With a current system, there's no harm done: the OP is going to lose their bounty anyway. With the proposed refund system, they will plain hate me for writing an answer which doesn't address the problem they "paid" to get solved. Essentially, I get to decide whether they get their bounty back or not.

Letting the OP decide whether the answer is good enough is even worse, as they will have a direct incentive to keep the bounty for themselves.